# MVC - Need suggestions to implemente MVC pattern with a Custom application in Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller

Consider the below screen shot showing a custom application built using Java.

[image]

1) In this custom application, we can add People and Cars as shown in above screen in a "View Port".

2) I am trying to write a Plugin for this custom application which does the below

- Reads all the Person object in view port
- Reads all Car objects in view port
- Reads all the attributes of person and car to see if there is a link, and produces
  output if there is a link.

Now, i am trying to implement the plugin using below MVC model

[image]

Based on this model, i have placed all the view like JPanel, Buttons etc., in view file,
Button click actions in Controller. But when creating Models, i met up with a confusion.

In the plugin i create, i donot have direct access to any of the database tables. Instead the
custom application provides me below functions

```
- getObjectsInViewPort()
- getObjectType(object)
- getProperties(object) etc.,
```

Now, how do i design my model? should i just create some method in model which would use the above
inbuilt models and returns some result to my controller which then sent to view for update?

or please provide me how should i do the MVC in proper way in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You are on a right track. To build a model, you don't have to have access to database.

**1)** Build your model

**2)** Call API functions from your model

**3)** Get the return result in your model

**4)** Give it to controller

**5)** Which in turn will present it to view.

**Answer Updated**

All business processing functions too will go in your model because this is your business model and not a POJO. Use data layer design pattern where you create POJOs to store your business data(API returned data) and then use them in your model classes to exchange with controllers.

Comment: Ok. I have do implement things like getPerson / getCars / getRelation in the models, is this ok? because in most of the Model class example, i can see only get and set methods. is it valid to do data processing in models?

Comment: It is your business model and not just POJO so answer is definitely yes. If we are talking about design patterns then use data layer design pattern where you create POJOs and store all your returned data in that and then use get,set or any other business processing functions in your model class.

Answer (score 0):

Simply start writing the model providing listeners, concentrate on the controller listening, invoking. Make abstract (mock-up) view classes that trigger events and such. *Scenario based, with a "stories".*

That would allow to write unit tests that play a scenario.

In a next phase take such a view class and *extend* it from JFrame or other GUI class. Or embed the abstract view class.